# How to get membershiplevel from Wordpress Database?

Tags: database, buddypress, membership

I have a quick question and I hope some of you can help me out.

The thing is I have this plugin that can put a badge to a profile picture manually. But since my website is a community it would be kind of a pain in the a** (sorry for the language) if I have to put the badge manually for every user with a certain role.

I try to do that automatically but I'm stuck on the part where I need to get the user ids from all premium users (s2member_level1)so that I can check a box in the backend automatically.

I'm searching for the correct code that simply does this logic here:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="1" 
  <?php  
    if (get all users with membership level "s2member_level1") {echo 'checked'; }
    else {echo'';} 
   ?> 
/>
```

All i have for now is this:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="1" <?php    echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Here is a screenshot of how it should looks like if the user has the s2member_level1:

[image: screenshot]

I coustomized this in the admin.php of the Plugin BuddyVerified version 2.2. 
This is the relevant code from the admin.php that generates the form shown in the screenshot:

```
function buddyverified_inner_meta_box() {

$user_id = isset($_GET['user_id']) ? $_GET['user_id'] : 0;
$meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'bp-verified', true) ? get_user_meta( $user_id, 'bp-verified', true) : null ;
$verified = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'bp-profile-verified', true) ? get_user_meta( $user_id, 'bp-profile-verified', true) : null ;

?>


<table cellspacing="3px" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">Verify User:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="verified" value="1" <?php  echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">Badge:</td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo VERIFIED_URL; ?>/images/5.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td></td>

            <td><input type="radio" name="verified_image" value="5" <?php if ($meta['image'] == '5') echo 'checked="checked"' ?> /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:middle">Badge Text:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="verified_text" name="verified_text" placeholder="Verified User" value="<?php echo $meta['text'] ?>" size="25" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alt">
            <td >Activity Badge:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="verified_activity" value="yes" <?php echo 'checked="checked"' ?> />Yes </td>
            <td><p>Adds badge to activity stream avatar</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >Profile Badge:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="verified_profile" value="yes" <?php if ( $meta['profile'] == 'yes') echo 'checked="checked"' ?> />Yes </td>
            <td><p>Adds badge to profile avatar</p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>    

<?php

}
```

I'm currently working with Wordpress Version 4.6.1, Buddypress 2.7.2 and s2Member Framework Version 2.7.3

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that s2Member does not bring the functionality out of the box. So I may not have a direct answer to your question, but a few suggestions instead:

- In your case I would probably try to combine s2Member with myCred (https://mycred.me/add-ons/badges/) for example like this: the only way to earn *'points'* would be upgrading to a pro account / role. Then a badge would be applied and displayed respectively.
- Another option could be to use [get_queried_object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to get the user role – then adjust the output accordingly: "[Show different badge based upon the user role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59947/show-different-badge-based-upon-the-user-role)"
- A third probably a but more complex option could be to use the plugin BadgeOS: *'… a powerful free plugin to WordPress that lets you easily create achievements and issue sharable badges as your users succeed. '* (http://badgeos.org/)
- Last but not least: I'm personally actually using PMPro instead of s2members – and they offer an add-on that would do just that: *'Assign unique member badges (images) to each membership level and display via a shortcode or template PHP function'*  (https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/add-ons/plus-add-ons/member-badges/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the first sugestion and its not working out for me. I tried using PMPro instead of s2member before but since i need the extra profile fields that i can assign to the different levels with s2member it's not an option too. so i will try the second suggestion. maybe that will work out.